# Add fields based on number (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add X fields according to the number type in the number field or so when the value increases.

My template:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-10 col-form-label">{l s='Nombre de voyageurs' mod='blocksouhaits'}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nbVoyager">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastnameVoyager" placeholder="Nom">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstnameVoyager" placeholder="Prénom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Depending on the value in the nbVoyager field I would like to add X row with the lastnameVoyager and firstnameVoyager fields.

How can I do this in a simple clean way?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a loop, such as [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), then [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone)/[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append) the `form-group` in each iteration. If you try that and still have issues please edit the question to show your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.change(function()` to detect changes made in the input fiels and the take the `val()` of the field and loop it that many times. Then in the loop you can `append`the wanted `div` with your `html` code

```js
$( "#nbVoyager" ).change(function() {
  var rows = $(this).val();
  $(".last").empty();
  $(".first").empty();
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) { 
      $(".first").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastnameVoyager" placeholder="Nom">');
      $(".last").append('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstnameVoyager" placeholder="Prénom">');      
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-10 col-form-label">{l s='Nombre de voyageurs' mod='blocksouhaits'}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nbVoyager">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 last"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 first"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code but there is a problem when there are 3 it displays 4 etc ...

Comment: @Chris99391 should be fixed now but the "up down" buttons are a little buggy dont know why... but try to manually insert a number